# Running a Selenium test as TestNG in Eclipse does not start Chrome browser

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testng, selenium-chromedriver

Any ideas why I can not get Selenium tests to open up Chrome, but they still get executed when looking at the console in Eclipse? The tests are passing, and I don't get any error messages.

Comment: Are you using headless mode?

Comment: Can you post your code.

Comment: @MateMrše I don't even know. These are ran also in Jenkins thought.

Comment: Can you please an example test code? If you are running headless, you are not supposed to see Chrome opened.

Comment: @MateMrše actually you were right. There was addArguments("--headless") added which I totally missed! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running tests in "headless" mode.

It's a way to run the Chrome browser in a headless environment, starting from Chrome 59. A headless browser is a great tool for automated testing and server environments where you don't need a visible UI shell.

When you are running headless, you are not supposed to see Chrome opened.

Comment: plus1 for that valuable comment.